# javascript Как получить список объявленных классов на странице?

Tags: javascript, классы, list

javascript. Можно ли сегодня на голом браузере каким-то образом обратиться к классу по строковому имени?

```js
class AClass {
  constructor() {

  }

  toString() {
    alert("Hello, world!");
  }
}

let className = $("div").attr("className");
let classType = window[className];
let instance = new classType();
console.log(instance.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="AClass">
```

Comment: не понятно чего вы пытаетесь добиться, может быть Вы нам расскажете предпосылки?

Comment: да, конечно. есть html, в котором <div className="AClass">. Мне необходимо по имени класса создать объект.

Answer (score 0):

Можно это сделать как-то так:

```js
class AClass {
  constructor(){}
  toString() {return 'AClass'}
}

class BClass {
  constructor(){}
  toString() {return 'BClass'}
}

document.querySelectorAll('div').forEach(div => {
  let ref = window[div.className];
  ref && (div.textContent= new ref().toString());
})
```

```html
<div class="AClass"></div>
<div class="BClass"></div>
```

Comment: так я получаю "Uncaught TypeError: window.AClass is not a constructor". Google chrome

Comment: сниппет работает благодаря установленной галочке use babel, вы же сами используете классы в вопросе, естественно в голом виде браузер это не прожевал

Comment: собственно вопрос и заключается в том, можно ли сегодня на голом браузере обратиться к классу по строковому имени.

Comment: @Александр в таком случае наверное необходимо это написать в вопросе

Comment: спасибо за помощь. правильно задать вопрос - полдела сделать.

Comment: @Александр можно сделать тожесамое что делает babel и создать функции, которые вызовут нужные конструкторы или через eval, я дополню ответ попозже, убежал от компа

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключается в том, что определения класса, в отличие от функций не добавляются в глобальный объект автоматически, даже если объявлены глобально.

Поэтому решением может стать только ручное объявление нужной переменной:

```js
class AClass {
  constructor() {

  }

  toString() {
    return ("Hello, world!");
  }
}
var classess = {
  AClass
};

let className = $("div").attr("className");
let classType = classess[className];
let instance = new classType();
console.log(instance.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="AClass">
```

Answer (score 0):

все очень просто оказалось, как обычно.
недостатком могу отметить только то, что это var со всеми своими hoisting и redeclare. в целом - приемлемо. всем спасибо за помощь.

```js
var AClass = class
{
  constructor()
  {

  }

  toString()
  {
    return ("Hello, world!");
  }
}

let className = $("div").attr("className");
let classType = window[className];
let instance = new classType();
console.log(classType.name + ': ' + instance.toString());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div className="AClass"></div>
```

Comment: да именно это и было в моем ответе

Comment: я ни в коем случае не намерен присвоить себе чей-то ответ, последнее что я видел - предложение обратиться к eval, что, кстати, вполне годно оказалось, но eval типа фу.

Comment: да, eval это дыра